# How to get a custom value from an array item

Tags: android, arrays

Lets say I have an array.xml like this ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="MyArray">
        <item deg="5">A</item>
        <item deg="55">B</item>
        <item deg="90">C</item>
    </string-array>
<resources>
```

I want to get the "deg" value from first item;

```
int array = getResources().getIdentifier("MyArray", "array", getPackageName());

String[] myArr = getResources().getStringArray(array);
```

And then something to work like that(example);

```
int degs = myArr[0].get("deg");
```

so finally degs variable gives me the "5". I have searched but I can't find any solution. Is there any way to do this like in my example code?

How can I get the value in deg="" ?

Comment: you cannot specify attributes for <item>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is clear enough and sane but that isn't how the resources work. The android tools simply don't see your custom deg field and the values are simply ignored.

I believe the most direct solution is to defined a similar numeric array to define the angles such as

```
<integer-array name="MyArrayVals">
    <item>5</item>
    <item>55</item>
    <item>90</item>
</integer-array>
```

Then you simple index the value at MyArrayVals according to the user's selected index in MyArray.
This solutiom, requires that you, as the maintainer, assure the one to one relationship between the indexes in your MyArray and the positions in MyArrayVals is valid.

Comment: I see. It would be easier if it is possible to specify custom attributes. 
Anyways, thank you I will do as you said.